# Strip map with horizontal labels in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: labeling, arcgis-pro, rotate, map-series

[image]

I've created a strip index page for my map series in ArcGIS Pro using the Generate Rectangles Along Lines tool. My problem is that the horizontal labels do not rotate with the map frame on the layout. The labels always point toward the north, even though the north is not directed toward the top of the layout. Is there a way to fix this?

I added an image to clarify the situation. On the layouts (shaped like the blocks) the blue line is horizontal, which is what I want. However, I want the labels to be displayed in the same direction.

Comment: Out of curiousity: Why are your maps not aligned to the north? That's rather contra-inductive.

Comment: The maps are oriented around a line, so for each map the line is displayed (almost) horizontally.

Comment: Have you added the Strip map index feature to the Data driven pages? There you can specify the angle, which should be a field in the strip map index feature, so that when you go to layout view the labels should also have the same direction.

Comment: In QGis there is the option `free` which orients the label accordingly to the polygons. Maybe Arc provides something similar. Though, I would place the number in a text field below the legend instead of somewhere on the map itself - thus it is more obvious.

Comment: @birks As far as I know there is no strip map index feature in ArcGIS Pro. I did specify the angle when I created the map series, so the maps are rotated, but the labels don't rotate with the map unfortunately.

Comment: @Erik An option like that is what I need, but I haven't found it yet unfortunately.

Comment: @Toothless Thats weird. The labels follows the "up" of the map in my layout view after I activate the Map Series.

Comment: @birks Thanks so much, I didn't know that was supposed to happen. I created a new project to test it and now the labels indeed follow the "up" of the map in my layout view. I guess there must be something wrong with the settings in my original project, so I'm going to try and figure out what it is.

Comment: This is the default behaviour in Pro. Label Class > Orientation > Graticule Alignment > Straight (change from None) See answer below

Answer (score 0):

In the Label Class properties, under "Position" tab, change the Orientation -> Graticule Alignment None (default) to Straight.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Under Map Properties (sometimes called Data Frame Properties), navigate to the "Labels" tab and unselect the option to "Rotate point and polygon labels when map is rotated"

[image: A snip of the map properties menu showing the option to rotate labels has been disabled]